# htaccess folder organization and rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble figuring out how to work a rewrite, or even if it is a good idea.

I would like to name my folders in my webroot the following way for the sake of organization:

```
_fol.A
_fol.B
_fol.C
```

But I would like, using .htaccess mod_rewrite, people to reach the above folders when they visit

```
http://example.com/Alpha
http://example.com/Bravo
http://example.com/Charlie
```

Is this just over-complicating my life so that I can have my folders all appear together?

Comment: You'd need a different `RewriteRule` for each... What's wrong with naming all of your folders `Alpha`, `Bravo`, `Charlie` to begin with?

Comment: Well `RewriteMap` _would_ be the weapon of choice here – but unfortunately this directive can only be used in the server/virtual host config, so usually no way on shared hosting. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)

Comment: The names are not actually in alphabetical order like that. When viewing the file structure, they're all mixed in with my php files when I'd like them to be all at the top in a group. But it is possible with RewriteRules?

Comment: I do have a dedicated virtual server, so I'll look into the RewriteMap

Comment: Rather than changing the server configuration and renaming a bunch of directories, have you considered configuring whatever tools you're using to list directories before files? Failing that, have you considered adding `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` to .htaccess, then renaming the directories and creating symlinks pointing the old names to the new? That seems like it'd be both more obvious and easier to maintain than doing it with `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Those are really good ideas, thanks. Solves my problem without unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's valid to group the folders in the physical _fol. I do this with products, where the url will be simply the product name /alpha, but they are in a products/alpha folder. This separates them nicely from the rest of the stuff on the website.

The other comments address your question of whether you're over-complicating, e.g., consider using the final names, and just put them down in the folder for organization.

That said, to answer how to do it, as CBroe said in the comments, `RewriteMap` is the answer.

This is one that doesn't rely on any particular url pattern - the product itself is the entire url. The RewriteCond line is making sure that it is in the map file. Keep or remove the leading slash in front of _fol as needed.

```
RewriteMap map_folder txt:d:\somepath\map_folder.txt [NC]

# Map folders.
RewriteCond ${map_folder:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule (.*) /_fol.${map_folder:$1} [NC,L]
```

The map_folder.txt file has entries like these:

```
Alpha A
Bravo B
Charlie C
```

If it's some other url, like /help, then it won't be found in the map file, and will fall through to further rules.

Comment: This seems like a good way to go, though I'd warn people that even with a VPS (on my host at least), you have to put the RewriteMap line in the httpd.conf, and where exactly I still haven't figured out yet.